# Use Google Analytics service with API key

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-api-client, google-authentication

I'm trying to make requests to Google Analytics, from my server. Thus, I'd like to avoid using Oauth.

One way to perform requests without authenticating is by using an API_KEY with this kind of URL :

`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=yesterday&ids={   GA_TABLE_ID}&key={API_KEY}&metrics=ga%3Asessions&start-date=30daysAgo`

But I have no idea of how to create such an API_KEY.

I tried creating one in the Google Developers Console but I always get the following result with this key :

`{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}`

Is it possible I have to link my Google Analytics project with my Google Developers Console someway ?